# docker-compose.yml file structure and name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dtd

I'm using Docker Compose V3 in a project, however when I run

```
docker compose up -d
```

in the Docker client app is displayed the name of the folder inside which it's located the `docker-compose.yml` file...

For this reason, I've looked for something like a `container_name` but for the whole project, not only for a single container, and I'm unable to find it

Furthermore, if not looking at the examples, there is no reference to a "general structure" of the `docker-compose.yml` file, something like a DTD for XML

I know that there is no way to create that DTD because at some point, keys and values depends on the containers, but at least for the first 3/4 layer of depth maybe there is a way or it's reported somewhere (somewhere that I'm not able to find)

So my question is, is there an alternative for `container_name` for the whole `docker-compose.yml`? Are there any DTD for the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: there is the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` that you can define in the compose level, full the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name). Is it something you are looking for?

Comment: @LucasBazetto where should I put this variable in the `docker-compose`?

Comment: you need to add a `.env` file at the same level as the docker-compose, and the content will be like `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=awesome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker works with services (containers) therefore Docker engine generate a unique ID and a more-readably name for every containers. **In default case the 1st part** of the container name is **the directory name** where is the docker-compose.yml file found and **the second part is the service name** which you defined in the docker-compose.yml file.

As Lucas Bazetto wrote you can override the 1st part of the containers name with the **COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=example_container_name_prefix** option in the **.env** file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by

```
docker compose -p {{MY_STACK_NAME}} up -d
```

to override what it takes from the yaml folder name.

Let me know if it works for you too.

Regards.

Comment: thank you, however I'm looking for a solution that does not pollute the composer up command